# PHP background from another php script

Tags: php, background, pipe

I've got a usual console (.*exe) program that accepts and outputs commands using standard `I/O`. I wrote a php script that handles the program (with `open_proc` etc):

```
<?php
/*
scriptname: somemyscript.php
*/

$descriptorspec = array(
   0 => array("pipe", "r"), 
   1 => array("pipe", "w"),  
   2 => array('pipe', 'a')
);

$cwd = NULL;
$env = NULL;

$process = proc_open('someconsoleprogram.exe', $descriptorspec, $pipes, $cwd, $env);
if (is_resource($process)) {

    stream_set_blocking($pipes[0], FALSE);
    stream_set_blocking($pipes[1], FALSE);

  while (true) {
    $changed = $write = $pipes;


    if (@stream_select($changed, $write, $except = NULL, NULL) < 1)
            continue;

    foreach ($changed as $changed_stream) {

                    some code;
    }

    foreach ($write as $write_stream) {

                    some code;

    }

    } 
  }

  fclose($pipes[0]);
  fclose($pipes[1]);


  $return_value = proc_close($process);

}
```

there is no problem there. But I need it to run as a daemon so I wrote:

```
<?php
/*
scriptname: somemyscriptbgnd.php
*/
$cmd = 'php somemyscript.php';
execInBackground($cmd);

function execInBackground($cmd) {
if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){ 
$handle = popen("start /B ". $cmd, 'r');
pclose($handle);  
} 
else { 
exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &");   
} 
}
```

So when I run `somemyscript.php` manually it works fine. 
However when I run `somemyscriptbgnd.php` - `somemyscript.php` works just a some moment - in simple words `somemyscriptbgnd.php` closes it as `pclose` closes the handle.

The question is `what a problem that may be and  how to launch somemyscript in background from another PHP script?`
N.B. I need the process would be run from the script - things as cron etc isn't suitable.

Answer (score 0):

why don't use system() thats if you're on windows but basically the answer to your problem is to redirect your output to dev/null 'cos according to php manual, php_exec func wont work async if its output isnt processed, so finally its

```
<?php exec("php 'yourscript.php' > /dev/null >/dev/null &"); ?>
```

nohup is optional depending on your code / file
you can also try for 
`'command' | at now`

hope you got it good bro.